# Dynamically hide form fields, without writing JavaScript myself, in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, ruby-on-rails-4, simple-form

I have a form where there's a user-selectable boolean early on in the form, and later on there's some fields that should be hidden if the boolean is false.

As Rails wouldn't know beforehand whether the boolean is true or false, I can't directly write a conditional in Ruby that handles this scenario.

I assume that it'd be possible to write JavaScript that could handle this. However, I'm currently assuming that the less JavaScript I have to write myself, the better.

Are there any gems out there that handle this scenario, presumably by generating the necessary JavaScript on my behalf?

This doesn't involve nested forms, so cocoon isn't relevant here.

I'm using Rails 4, and simple_form.

Comment: Looks really likea  client side issue so I think you really have to deal with js yourself. Is a very specific situation and I think you can solve it with two lines of js with no help of a gem or something

Comment: Yeah I believe in this case the situation is so simple that no one created a library for it, so javascript is your best bet.